# Fill pandas dataframe with specific values from json

Tags: python, json, pandas, iteration, dataframe

I have a very large, deeply nested json, from which I need only some key-values pairs, not all of them. Because it's very deeply nested, it's not comfortable to create a pandas dataframe directly from the json, because all the values I need will not be in columns.

I need to create pandas dataframe that should look like:

```
Groupe      Id   MotherName   FatherName
Advanced    56   Laure         James
Middle      11   Ann           Nicolas
Advanced    6    Helen         Franc
```

From my complex json I extract the values I need as follows (All the values are extracted correctly so there is no error here):

```
jfile=json.loads(data)
groupe=jfile['location']['groupe']
id=jfile['id']
MotherName=jfile['Mother']['MotherName']
FatherName=jfile['Father']['FatherName']
```

jfile looks like:

`{"location":{"town":"Rome","groupe":"Advanced",
"school":{"SchoolGroupe":"TrowMet", "SchoolName":"VeronM"}},
"id":"145",
"Mother":{"MotherName":"Helen","MotherAge":"46"},"NGlobalNote":2,
"Father":{"FatherName":"Peter","FatherAge":"51"},
"Teacher":["MrCrock","MrDaniel"],"Field":"Marketing","season":["summer","spring"]}`

Then I create an empty dataframe and try to fill it with these values:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['group', 'id', 'Father', 'Mother'])
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    row['groupe']=jfile['location']['groupe']
    row['id']=jfile['id']
    row['MotherName']=jfile['Father']['FatherName']
    row['id']=jfile['Mother']['MotherName']
```

but when I try to print it, it says the dataframe is empty:

> Empty DataFrame Columns: [groupe, id, MotherName, FatherName] Index:
>   []

Why is it empty with this method, and how I can fill it properly?

Comment: Can you add sample of `jfile`, which is converted to desired output?

Comment: @jezrael I've just updated the question with the example of jfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to add a single row to your dataframe, you can use

```
df = df.append({"groupe":group,"id":id,"MotherName":MotherName,"FatherName":FatherName},
                ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This is a very convenient method, but is it really the fastest way to build up a DataFrame? What about creating a list or dictionary first and converting it into a DataFrame later, might that be faster?

Comment: @koalo yes what you suggest is the usual way.